# Calendar TypeConverter for Room (Kotlin)

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components, typeconverter

I am trying to persist a timestamp in my room database using the following `TypeConverter`:

```
class Converters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Calendar? {

        if(value == null) return null

        val cal = GregorianCalendar()
        cal.timeInMillis = value
        return cal
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toTimestamp(timestamp: Calendar?): Long? {

        if(timestamp == null) return null

        return timestamp.timeInMillis
    }
}
```

Two of my Entities include the following column
:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp")
val timestamp: Calendar?,
```

But I get a compilation error upon trying to build the project - I had no issues when using the `Date` `TypeConverter` example from the developer reference guide.

I am unable to see what the actual error is as I just get a bunch of databinding 'cannot find symbol' errors if there is something wrong with the code related to Room.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use:

```
object Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Calendar? = value?.let { value ->
        GregorianCalendar().also { calendar ->
            calendar.timeInMillis = value
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun toTimestamp(timestamp: Calendar?): Long? = timestamp?.timeInMillis
}
```

And

```
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
```

Comment: Using class instead of object you can avoid the using of @JvmStatic. Object class works as singleton, so that's the reason why all methods inside an object are static.